# When abruptly exiting a C program mid-loop, why do additional loop iterations occur?

Tags: c, linux, loops, fedora-25

Consider the basic client and server programs below (just bare bones / to illustrate my question). The client initiates a connection with the server, prompts the user to enter a message, which is then sent to the server and printed to screen.

If I abruptly quit the client program in the middle of the loop (e.g. by closing the terminal window), sometimes the client will continue to iterate through the loop for a period of time (i.e. the last message sent to the server / currently residing in the write buffer at the time the client is closed, is repeatedly sent to the server, typically until the loop is exhausted). Other times however, the read() call on the server correctly returns 0, and the connection is closed without issue (the behavior seems to be fairly random).

I don't quite understand what's going on here. First off, why do additional loop iterations occur after the program closes? Is there just a lag time between when the terminal window is closed, and when the actual process itself ends? Even if additional loop iterations do occur, shouldn't the call to fgets() block until a message is entered by the user?

I'm using Fedora 25 Workstation with XFCE desktop.

I tried searching for info on this, but didn't have much luck (I'm not sure how to search for this in a succinct way). Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

CLIENT:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    struct sockaddr_in server;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(3000);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &server.sin_addr);
    connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server));

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        char buf[512];
        printf("Send a message: ");
        fgets(buf, 512, stdin);
        write(sockfd, buf, sizeof(buf));
    }

    close(sockfd);
}
```

SERVER:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    int listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    struct sockaddr_in server;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(3000);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &server.sin_addr);
    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server));

    listen(listenfd, 10);
    printf("Listening...\n");

    struct sockaddr_in client;
    socklen_t client_size = sizeof(client);
    int clientfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &client_size);

    for (;;) {
        char buf[512];
        int i = read(clientfd, buf, sizeof(buf));

        if (i == 0) {
            close(clientfd);
            printf("Connection Closed\n");
            break;
        } else {
            printf("%s", buf);
        }
    }

    close(listenfd);
}
```

Comment: You'll need to give details about your operating system , window manager etc.

Comment: Its likely that when you close the terminal, stdin become invalid for brief amount of time(large enough to let the loop complete),
making fgets return immediately letting loop continue till end, by the time OS detects the processes it to be stopped your program is done running.
If you kill it with kill -9 does is behave same way?

Comment: Check the return value for `fgets` - if it is null exit the loop

Comment: In general, you are not checking for errors. For example, `write()` does not always succeed but you don't know. Also `fgets()` will return `NULL` and so on, check the return value of every function that has a return value, it has a meaning that you can learn by simply typing `man funcion_name` on the terminal, do so, and when you make sure you understood all such return values and you handled them, then you will understand what is exactly happening. You can't tell because you don't handle errors, but it's certainly not really random, you just don't know which error occurs when.

Comment: Also, note that `printf("%s", buf)` is most likely UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR, because `buf` is not necessarily a string. You should ensure it is such a thing before using it as one. And you don't check whether `clientfd` is actually a valid file descriptor after `accept()`. The pattern seems to be really that, a pattern in your code. Fix that, handle every possible error and you will understand what's going on.

Comment: In `client`, move `char buf[512];` outside the loop and then get rid of the `for` loop and use something similar to `while (fgets(buf, 512, stdin)) { ... }`

Comment: note: the function: `read()` returns a `ssize_t` not an `int`

Comment: Thanks a bunch for all the help. fgets() was indeed returning NULL whenever the additional iterations occurred. Adding a check for this solves the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your terminal (and thus the remote/master side of the pty device connected to your process's stdin/out/err) is closed, `fgets` will see end-of-file status on `stdin`, and will return immediately with either an incomplete line (not ending in `\n`) or no input at all (null return value); in practice it's going to be the latter. If you checked the result, you would see this and be able to act accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this is indeed what was going on. fgets() is returning NULL whenever the additional iterations occur. Checking for this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

in the server, this line:

```
printf("%s", buf);
```

should be replaced with:

```
*buf[i] = '\n'; 
printf( "%s", buf );
```

so there is a valid string to print (`read()` will not terminate the string)

Note: if a I/O error occurs or a signal occurs, etc then `read()` will return a value less than 0 and should result in exiting the for(;;;) loop, not continuing in the loop, printing the 'old' contents of `buf[]`

in this line in the client:

```
write(sockfd, buf, sizeof(buf));
```

if the write fails, it will return a value less than 0  if/when such an event occurs, the loop should exit, not continue looping,

It is very important to check all error conditions.   such error checking (and the resulting handling of the error) can easily double the size of the code, but it must be done; otherwise such 'odd' events as you are seeing will happen, with no simple explanation of what happened.

When a system function returns an error indication, use the function `perror()`  to have some text you provide displayed on `stderr`, along with the message from the system as to why it thinks the error occurred.

Comment: Did you mean `buf[i] = '\0';`? But that can still write outside the buffer. `printf("%.*s", i, buf);` would be better (or just use `fwrite`).

Comment: This actually makes things worse -- the client is sending an entire 512 byte buffer including the terminating NUL it got from fgets, so the read probably returns 512, meaning you're storing a newline after the end of the buffer resulting in undefined behavior.

Comment: @melpomene, Your right about using '\0' rather than '\n'.  The client has a problem in sending the whole `buf[]`, most of which will 'usually'  not have valid data.  The call to `write()` should be: `write(sockfd, buf, strlen(buf));` which will never send more that 511 bytes.  Sorry I missed that detail when I originally wrote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> If I abruptly quit the client program in the middle of the loop (e.g. by closing the terminal window),

Closing the terminal window does not quit the client program -- it continues running, just with no input (so any reads from the now-closed terminal will return EOF).  However, you never check the return value of `fgets` in the client so you you never notice, you just keep looping, sending the same buffer.

In addition, the code:

```
fgets(buf, 512, stdin);
write(sockfd, buf, sizeof(buf));
```

reads a line of up to 511 chars from the input, but then sends the entire 512 byte buffer, regardless of how long the actual message is.  What you want is something more like:

```
if (fgets(buf, 512, stdin))
    write(sockfd, buf, strlen(buf));
else
    break;  // there was an error or EOF on reading from stdin
```

Of course, this still has issues with lines longer than 511 bytes and then there's the issue that TCP does not preserve message boundaries, so on the server you might get more than one or only part of a message in a single read call.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't familiar with the behavior of stdin/stdout when the terminal window is closed. Checking the return value of fgets() did solve the problem (NULL is returned if additional iterations occur after the terminal window is closed).